# How to suppress Apache Hive from logging to the screen?

Tags: hive, log4j, hiveql

I have Apache Hive 3.1.2 and Hadoop 3.2.1 installed on my Win 10 machine. I was able to initialize the Derby DB and get the Hive CLI working. The only problem is that when I launch the Hive CLI it's printing out too much logging to the screen making it very difficult to work with:

```
PS C:> hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/Hadoop/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/Hadoop/Hive/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2021-12-31 21:29:47,837 INFO conf.HiveConf: Found configuration file file:/D:/Hadoop/Hive/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/conf/hive-site.xml
Hive Session ID = ea6f139b-ada0-4da3-92cd-a86e7e583365
2021-12-31 21:29:49,602 INFO SessionState: Hive Session ID = ea6f139b-ada0-4da3-92cd-a86e7e583365

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/D:/Hadoop/Hive/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/hive-common-3.1.2.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
2021-12-31 21:29:49,653 INFO SessionState:
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/D:/Hadoop/Hive/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/hive-common-3.1.2.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
2021-12-31 21:29:51,700 INFO session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/bluet/ea6f139b-ada0-4da3-92cd-a86e7e583365
2021-12-31 21:29:51,703 INFO session.SessionState: Created local directory: C:/Users/bluet/AppData/Local/Temp/bluet/ea6f139b-ada0-4da3-92cd-a86e7e583365
2021-12-31 21:29:51,728 INFO session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/bluet/ea6f139b-ada0-4da3-92cd-a86e7e583365/_tmp_space.db
2021-12-31 21:29:51,739 INFO conf.HiveConf: Using the default value passed in for log id: ea6f139b-ada0-4da3-92cd-a86e7e583365
2021-12-31 21:29:51,739 INFO session.SessionState: Updating thread name to ea6f139b-ada0-4da3-92cd-a86e7e583365 main
2021-12-31 21:29:52,575 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implementation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
2021-12-31 21:29:52,599 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.autoStartMechanismMode is set to unsupported value null . Setting it to value: ignored
2021-12-31 21:29:52,602 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
2021-12-31 21:29:52,604 INFO conf.MetastoreConf: Found configuration file file:/D:/Hadoop/Hive/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/conf/hive-site.xml
2021-12-31 21:29:52,605 INFO conf.MetastoreConf: Unable to find config file hivemetastore-site.xml
2021-12-31 21:29:52,605 INFO conf.MetastoreConf: Found configuration file null
2021-12-31 21:29:52,606 INFO conf.MetastoreConf: Unable to find config file metastore-site.xml
2021-12-31 21:29:52,606 INFO conf.MetastoreConf: Found configuration file null
2021-12-31 21:29:52,737 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
2021-12-31 21:29:52,910 INFO hikari.HikariDataSource: HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-12-31 21:29:53,025 INFO pool.PoolBase: HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Feature not implemented: getNetworkTimeout.)
2021-12-31 21:29:53,045 INFO hikari.HikariDataSource: HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-12-31 21:29:53,091 INFO hikari.HikariDataSource: HikariPool-2 - Starting...
2021-12-31 21:29:53,093 INFO pool.PoolBase: HikariPool-2 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Feature not implemented: getNetworkTimeout.)
2021-12-31 21:29:53,094 INFO hikari.HikariDataSource: HikariPool-2 - Start completed.
2021-12-31 21:29:53,152 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
2021-12-31 21:29:53,230 INFO metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql: Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
2021-12-31 21:29:53,232 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
2021-12-31 21:29:53,388 WARN DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2021-12-31 21:29:53,389 WARN DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2021-12-31 21:29:53,390 WARN DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2021-12-31 21:29:53,392 WARN DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2021-12-31 21:29:53,392 WARN DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2021-12-31 21:29:53,393 WARN DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2021-12-31 21:29:54,732 WARN DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2021-12-31 21:29:54,732 WARN DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2021-12-31 21:29:54,733 WARN DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2021-12-31 21:29:54,735 WARN DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2021-12-31 21:29:54,735 WARN DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2021-12-31 21:29:54,736 WARN DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2021-12-31 21:29:56,637 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added admin role in metastore
2021-12-31 21:29:56,638 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added public role in metastore
2021-12-31 21:29:56,652 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
2021-12-31 21:29:56,799 INFO metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient: RetryingMetaStoreClient proxy=class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient ugi=bluet (auth:SIMPLE) retries=1 delay=1 lifetime=0
2021-12-31 21:29:56,819 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_all_functions
2021-12-31 21:29:56,821 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=bluet     ip=unknown-ip-addr      cmd=get_all_functions
Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
2021-12-31 21:29:56,844 INFO CliDriver: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
Hive Session ID = a881b5f9-13f9-4932-9fa0-46bd3384ae77
2021-12-31 21:29:56,845 INFO SessionState: Hive Session ID = a881b5f9-13f9-4932-9fa0-46bd3384ae77
2021-12-31 21:29:56,902 INFO session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/bluet/a881b5f9-13f9-4932-9fa0-46bd3384ae77
2021-12-31 21:29:56,905 INFO session.SessionState: Created local directory: C:/Users/bluet/AppData/Local/Temp/bluet/a881b5f9-13f9-4932-9fa0-46bd3384ae77
2021-12-31 21:29:56,935 INFO session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/bluet/a881b5f9-13f9-4932-9fa0-46bd3384ae77/_tmp_space.db
2021-12-31 21:29:56,939 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 1: get_databases: @hive#
2021-12-31 21:29:56,939 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=bluet     ip=unknown-ip-addr      cmd=get_databases: @hive#
2021-12-31 21:29:56,941 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 1: Opening raw store with implementation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
2021-12-31 21:29:56,942 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
2021-12-31 21:29:56,946 INFO metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql: Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
2021-12-31 21:29:56,947 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
2021-12-31 21:29:56,953 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 1: get_tables_by_type: db=@hive#default pat=.*,type=MATERIALIZED_VIEW
2021-12-31 21:29:56,953 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=bluet     ip=unknown-ip-addr      cmd=get_tables_by_type: db=@hive#default pat=.*,type=MATERIALIZED_VIEW
2021-12-31 21:29:56,958 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 1: get_multi_table : db=default tbls=
2021-12-31 21:29:56,958 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=bluet     ip=unknown-ip-addr      cmd=get_multi_table : db=default tbls=
2021-12-31 21:29:56,961 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 1: get_tables_by_type: db=@hive#hive_test pat=.*,type=MATERIALIZED_VIEW
2021-12-31 21:29:56,961 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=bluet     ip=unknown-ip-addr      cmd=get_tables_by_type: db=@hive#hive_test pat=.*,type=MATERIALIZED_VIEW
2021-12-31 21:29:56,964 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 1: get_multi_table : db=hive_test tbls=
2021-12-31 21:29:56,964 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=bluet     ip=unknown-ip-addr      cmd=get_multi_table : db=hive_test tbls=
2021-12-31 21:29:56,964 INFO metadata.HiveMaterializedViewsRegistry: Materialized views registry has been initialized
hive>
```

And if I give a simple command like `SHOW DATABASES` it's still showing too much logging to the screen:

```
hive> SHOW DATABASES;
2021-12-31 21:30:36,036 INFO conf.HiveConf: Using the default value passed in for log id: ea6f139b-ada0-4da3-92cd-a86e7e583365
2021-12-31 21:30:36,113 INFO ql.Driver: Compiling command(queryId=bluet_20211231213036_b77a2f03-e83c-4b17-b656-191825b54b3f): SHOW DATABASES
2021-12-31 21:30:36,785 INFO ql.Driver: Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
2021-12-31 21:30:36,803 INFO ql.Driver: Semantic Analysis Completed (retrial = false)
2021-12-31 21:30:36,852 INFO ql.Driver: Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:[FieldSchema(name:database_name, type:string, comment:from deserializer)], properties:null)
2021-12-31 21:30:36,918 INFO exec.ListSinkOperator: Initializing operator LIST_SINK[0]
2021-12-31 21:30:36,927 INFO ql.Driver: Completed compiling command(queryId=bluet_20211231213036_b77a2f03-e83c-4b17-b656-191825b54b3f); Time taken: 0.848 seconds
2021-12-31 21:30:36,927 INFO reexec.ReExecDriver: Execution #1 of query
2021-12-31 21:30:36,928 INFO ql.Driver: Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
2021-12-31 21:30:36,928 INFO ql.Driver: Executing command(queryId=bluet_20211231213036_b77a2f03-e83c-4b17-b656-191825b54b3f): SHOW DATABASES
2021-12-31 21:30:36,937 INFO ql.Driver: Starting task [Stage-0:DDL] in serial mode
2021-12-31 21:30:36,938 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_databases: @hive#
2021-12-31 21:30:36,938 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=bluet     ip=unknown-ip-addr      cmd=get_databases: @hive#
2021-12-31 21:30:36,941 INFO exec.DDLTask: results : 2
2021-12-31 21:30:36,949 INFO ql.Driver: Completed executing command(queryId=bluet_20211231213036_b77a2f03-e83c-4b17-b656-191825b54b3f); Time taken: 0.021 seconds
OK
2021-12-31 21:30:36,949 INFO ql.Driver: OK
2021-12-31 21:30:36,949 INFO ql.Driver: Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
2021-12-31 21:30:36,959 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
2021-12-31 21:30:36,995 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2021-12-31 21:30:37,011 INFO exec.ListSinkOperator: RECORDS_OUT_INTERMEDIATE:0, RECORDS_OUT_OPERATOR_LIST_SINK_0:2,
default
hive_test
Time taken: 0.873 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
2021-12-31 21:30:37,020 INFO CliDriver: Time taken: 0.873 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
2021-12-31 21:30:37,020 INFO conf.HiveConf: Using the default value passed in for log id: ea6f139b-ada0-4da3-92cd-a86e7e583365
2021-12-31 21:30:37,020 INFO session.SessionState: Resetting thread name to  main
```

Using the `hive -S` or `hive --silent` flag has no effect. It gives the same result as not using the flag at all!

In my `HIVE_HOME\conf\hive-log4j.default` I've tried bumping up the logging level by adding the following:

```
hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=ERROR,console
hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.root.logger=ERROR,console
hive --service hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.root.logger=ERROR,console start
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.hadoop").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
```

Also in my `$HIVE_HOME/conf` directory I've edited both the `hive-log4j2.properties` and the  `hive-exec-log4j2.properties` files to log only for `ERROR` level events.

In `hive-exec-log4j2.properties` I have:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional ERRORrmation
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

status = ERROR
name = HiveLog4j2
packages = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log

# list of properties
property.hive.log.level = ERROR
property.hive.root.logger = DRFA
property.hive.log.dir = ${sys:java.io.tmpdir}/${sys:user.name}
property.hive.log.file = hive.log
property.hive.perflogger.log.level = ERROR

# list of all appenders
appenders = console, DRFA

# console appender
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = console
appender.console.target = SYSTEM_ERR
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{ISO8601} %5p [%t] %c{2}: %m%n

# daily rolling file appender
appender.DRFA.type = RollingRandomAccessFile
appender.DRFA.name = DRFA
appender.DRFA.fileName = ${sys:hive.log.dir}/${sys:hive.log.file}
# Use %pid in the filePattern to append <process-id>@<host-name> to the filename if you want separate log files for different CLI session
appender.DRFA.filePattern = ${sys:hive.log.dir}/${sys:hive.log.file}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
appender.DRFA.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.DRFA.layout.pattern = %d{ISO8601} %5p [%t] %c{2}: %m%n
appender.DRFA.policies.type = Policies
appender.DRFA.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.DRFA.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.DRFA.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.DRFA.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.DRFA.strategy.max = 30

# list of all loggers
loggers = NIOServerCnxn, ClientCnxnSocketNIO, DataNucleus, Datastore, JPOX, PerfLogger, AmazonAws, ApacheHttp

logger.NIOServerCnxn.name = org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn
logger.NIOServerCnxn.level = ERROR

logger.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.name = org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO
logger.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.level = ERROR

logger.DataNucleus.name = DataNucleus
logger.DataNucleus.level = ERROR

logger.Datastore.name = Datastore
logger.Datastore.level = ERROR

logger.JPOX.name = JPOX
logger.JPOX.level = ERROR

logger.AmazonAws.name=com.amazonaws
logger.AmazonAws.level = ERROR

logger.ApacheHttp.name=org.apache.http
logger.ApacheHttp.level = ERROR

logger.PerfLogger.name = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log.PerfLogger
logger.PerfLogger.level = ${sys:hive.perflogger.log.level}

# root logger
rootLogger.level = ${sys:hive.log.level}
rootLogger.appenderRefs = root
rootLogger.appenderRef.root.ref = ${sys:hive.root.logger}
```

And in my `hive-exec-log4j2.properties` file I have:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional ERRORrmation
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

status = ERROR
name = HiveExecLog4j2
packages = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log

# list of properties
property.hive.log.level = ERROR
property.hive.root.logger = FA
property.hive.query.id = hadoop
property.hive.log.dir = ${sys:java.io.tmpdir}/${sys:user.name}
property.hive.log.file = ${sys:hive.query.id}.log

# list of all appenders
appenders = console, FA

# console appender
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = console
appender.console.target = SYSTEM_ERR
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{ISO8601} %5p [%t] %c{2}: %m%n

# simple file appender
appender.FA.type = RandomAccessFile
appender.FA.name = FA
appender.FA.fileName = ${sys:hive.log.dir}/${sys:hive.log.file}
appender.FA.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.FA.layout.pattern = %d{ISO8601} %5p [%t] %c{2}: %m%n

# list of all loggers
loggers = NIOServerCnxn, ClientCnxnSocketNIO, DataNucleus, Datastore, JPOX

logger.NIOServerCnxn.name = org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn
logger.NIOServerCnxn.level = ERROR

logger.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.name = org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO
logger.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.level = ERROR

logger.DataNucleus.name = DataNucleus
logger.DataNucleus.level = ERROR

logger.Datastore.name = Datastore
logger.Datastore.level = ERROR

logger.JPOX.name = JPOX
logger.JPOX.level = ERROR

# root logger
rootLogger.level = ${sys:hive.log.level}
rootLogger.appenderRefs = root
rootLogger.appenderRef.root.ref = ${sys:hive.root.logger}
```

And after those changes I'm starting the hive service with:

```
hive --service hiveserver2 start
```

But the problem remains! How can I correct that so that I suppress all that unnecessary logging to the screen (stdout)?

Comment: Have you tried editing or adding a og4j property file in the Hive conf folder?

Comment: I've added my `log4j` configuration to the post and added some detail. Thanks!

Comment: No, you need to actually make/edit a properties file, not try to modify the Hive/Spark config. See this command option https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/bin/hive#L383  Also note that beeline command is preferred for connections to HiveServer

Comment: How do I create / edit the properties file that it needs?

Comment: I see two properties templates in the conf directory of hive that might be of interest: `hive-exec-log4j2.properties.template` and `hive-log4j2.properties.template`.  So I would have to edit one of these files and change the name to remove the `.template` ending and restart the service to change the logging levels? Which one?

Comment: Both of them, if you want full control over the logging, but I only know about the second one

Comment: Ok I've edited both, restarted my machine and started up Hadoop and Hive. There's still no difference, I'm still getting excessive logging to the screen. I've updated the post with the configs for the `hive-exec-log4j2.properties` and `hive-log4j2.properties`.

Comment: Also I hear you about using the `beeline` command line, however I'm getting an error starting that too. `beeline` doesn't even start at this point.  I figure I'd like to tackle the problem I'm having with hive before I set out against the gnarly error I'm getting starting `beeline`. Thanks.